# Stop inter-node communication in elasticsearch (without using firewall to block ports)

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

I am looking to stop the inter-node communication in elasticsearch,basically to stop listening on port 9300.
Above should be achieved without using firewall to block any ports.

I tried closing the netty channel in the server bootstrap, if i do it elasticsearch wont start.

When i run elasticsearch instance it should not listen to 9300,

But i get below errors,
 [2019-03-25T10:46:16,344][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node-0] uncaught exception in thread [main]
[elasticsearch] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: handler not set
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: handler not set
[elasticsearch]         at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.validate(Bootstrap.java:284) ~[?:?]
[elasticsearch]         at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:113) ~[?:?]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.createClientBootstrap(Netty4Transport.java:189) ~[?:?]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:149) ~[?:?]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:61) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:228) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:61) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:661) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:263) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[elasticsearch]         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.0.0-SNAPSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the Single node discover ? 
single-node (configure it by setting `discovery.type` to `single-node`); in this situation, a node will elect itself master and will not join a cluster with any other node. This is more clean way of doing this

Also, it is possible to evade the bootstrap checks (either by not binding transport to an external interface, or by binding transport to an external interface and setting the discovery type to single-node)

Comment: Can you tell in which file should i set it to single node.

Comment: Is it Netty4transport.java ,by the way i am running elastic search in eclipse.

Comment: Should go in elasticsearch.yaml, more at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html

Comment: I am not using normal installer,how do set discovery.type in this file directly https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/node

Comment: It said ,either by not binding transport to an external interface, or by binding transport to an external interface ,does that mean it automatically chooses one or we get to set it.

Comment: Elasticsearch allows you to bind to multiple ports on different interfaces by the use of transport profiles and you can define them

Answer (score 0):

Set node.name to something other than 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: how does that serve my requirement